Passing a method as parameter in playwright
I have a function that checks a locator to have a certain text and i want to use first() and last() as parameters, among others:
export async function checkLocatorByText(page: Page,locatorName: string,locatorPosition:string, text: string) {
    await expect(page.locator(locatorName).last()).toContainText(text);
}

For example here I have a parameter locatorPosition that i would like to use instead of hardcoding the .last() method directly. I want to use the .last() method later as an argument but I am failing at using it in the function.
What result i really want is something like this
export async function checkLocatorByText(page: Page,locatorName: string,locatorPosition:string, text: string) {
    await expect(page.locator(locatorName).locatorName).toContainText(text);
}

How can i achieve this ?

I'd discourage this sort of dynamic function building from strings--the tests won't be very readable. Can you provide context for what you're trying to do?

Doing something like this you can pass either "first", "last" or the index of the locator you want to check:
  async checkLocatorByText(
    page: Page,
    locatorName: string,
    locatorPosition: "first" | "last" | number,
    text: string
  ) {
    if (locatorPosition === "first") {
      await expect(page.locator(locatorName).first()).toContainText(text);
    } else if (locatorPosition === "last") {
      await expect(page.locator(locatorName).last()).toContainText(text);
    } else {
      await expect(page.locator(locatorName).nth(locatorPosition)).toContainText(text);
    }
  }

